# How i can put generic class into the collection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I have generic -SomeClass which calculate absolute value for numbers and i want to put it in collection and then i want to get an object of class from this collection. 
I had already announced SomeClass and I want to write something like this:

```
 class Example<T>
{
    Collection<T> collection = new Collection<T>(); 

    public void AddSomeClassIntoCollection()
    {
        collection.Add(SomeClass<T>);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have *no* idea what you mean by `**SomeClass<T>**`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Example<T>
{
    Collection<T> collection = new Collection<T>(); 

    public void AddSomeClassIntoCollection(T item)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: I guess yes, i want to make a class with collection of classes and output collection's element

Comment: if you need a more descriptive answer, add more detail to your question

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the OP wanted `Collection<SomeClass<T>>` based on her add. Either way, the question needs more detail to be sure.